# XSSF Workbook identifier is returned as null for some users

Tags: java, apache-poi, xssf

I am using Apache POI Version 3.16. And I have set the identifier for the file being downloaded by users as below,

```
workbook.getProperties().getCoreProperties().setIdentifier("somevalue");
```

But for some users when I try to read the identifier of the file they downloaded, it is opting out as null.

I am trying to read the identifier as below, it is giving me as null.

```
workbook.getProperties().getCoreProperties().getIdentifier();
```

The users machine has Windows-10 OS and I am not sure it may be a version issue or whatever?

Comment: Maybe those users have [removed the hidden data and personal information by using Document Inspector](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/remove-hidden-data-and-personal-information-by-inspecting-documents-presentations-or-workbooks-356b7b5d-77af-44fe-a07f-9aa4d085966f). Maybe this is done automatically before upload using a policy.

Comment: @Axel Richer as you have mentioned, the document inspector is the one removing it. Is there anyway to make the workbook protected from document inspector and user policies in the system?